# Arduino IDE - debugging Exception 29

Tags: arduino-ide, nodemcu, debugging

I installed the ESP EXCEPTION DECODER along with my Arduino IDE.  When my sketch crashes with Exception 29, I take the stack trace and input it, but I can't understand its line references (they dont seem to point to my code).

> Exception (29):
>   epc1=0x4020ec84 epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x00000000 depc=0x00000000
>
> ctx: sys 
>   sp: 3ffffcd0 end: 3fffffb0 offset: 01a0
>
> 3ffffe70:  3fffb558 00000000 3fff197c fffffffb
>   3ffffe80:  3fff0ea0 3fff0ea0 00000000 4020fb20
>   3ffffe90:  00000000 00000000 0000001f fffffffb
>   3ffffea0:  3fff0ea0 00000000 3fff0e9c 4020ed35
>   3ffffeb0:  40000f68 3ffe93b4 3fff0e9c 402120ec
>   3ffffec0:  00000000 00000007 3fff197c 402137fa
>   3ffffed0:  3ffe93b4 3ffe93b4 3fff0e9c 4021211a
>   3ffffee0:  ffffffff 3fff0e9c 3fff197c 4021463c
>   3ffffef0:  0100a8c0 3fffdcb0 3ffee960 00000030
>   3fffff00:  00000000 3fff0e9c 3fff197c 4021468f
>   3fffff10:  4020ffa8 3fff0afc 3fff0fc4 40100690
>   3fffff20:  40229e46 00000000 00000012 3fff0af8
>   3fffff30:  4020ffa8 3fff0afc 3ffe9348 4020ffb6
>   3fffff40:  40104d7e 948e6801 00000018 40210074
>   3fffff50:  3ffe9348 3ffed9fc 948e6801 00000000
>   3fffff60:  4022e654 3ffee928 3ffee950 60000600
>   3fffff70:  0fc612e0 3ffee950 3ffee928 4022e661
>   3fffff80:  4022e6a6 3fffdab0 00000000 3fffdcb0
>   3fffff90:  3ffee968 40000f65 3fffdab0 00000000
>   3fffffa0:  40000f49 3ffe96e8 3fffdab0 40000f49
>   <<
>
> 0x4020fb20: tcp_abort at core/tcp.c line 544
>
> 0x4020ed35: netif_sta_status_callback at glue-lwip/lwip-git.c line 303
>
> 0x402120ec: netif_set_ipaddr at core/netif.c line 545
>
> 0x402137fa: dhcp_create_msg at core/ipv4/dhcp.c line 1825
>
> 0x4021211a: netif_set_addr_LWIP2 at core/netif.c line 584
>
> 0x4021463c: dhcp_release_LWIP2 at core/ipv4/dhcp.c line 1314
>
> 0x4021468f: dhcp_coarse_tmr at core/ipv4/dhcp.c line 423
>
> 0x4020ffa8: cyclic_timer at core/timeouts.c line 165
>
> 0x40100690: free at /home/tony/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.1/cores/esp8266/umm_malloc/umm_malloc.c line 1739
>
> 0x4020ffa8: cyclic_timer at core/timeouts.c line 165
>
> 0x4020ffb6: cyclic_timer at core/timeouts.c line 171
>
> 0x40210074: sys_check_timeouts at core/timeouts.c line 351

How can I find ou what happens at address `0x4020ec84` and what line it points to?

Comment: use the latest esp8266 arduino core 2.5.2.

Comment: done.  went in BOARDS MANAGER and upgraded core from 2.4.1 to 2.5.2 -  what next?

Comment: upgraded, must wait for problem to occur (historically it has taken 16+ hours to manifest itself - memory might be an issue)

Comment: do you use String class to build strings and convert numbers?

Comment: yes i do.  could that be the culprit?

Comment: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/evils-arduino-strings

Comment: @Juraj, apparently, your comment re `Strings` has pointed me in a valid direction, though it is not quite the answer to the question.  IMportantly, it solves my underlying issue.  I therefore awarded you the 50 bonus points in the other question.  well done, m8 !  ;)